# Mercedes Atego OBD2 live data codes

Tags: engine, electrical, mercedes-benz, obd-ii, truck

I have tried to connect an OBDII ELM327 adapter in Mercedes Atego. 
Somehow I managed to get it in that OBD2 connector. I can see that my adapter is receiving electricity. These are the PID's that I can read with this adapter: [OBD PID's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs). But as I thought these PID's are not working in the Mercedes atego.

Is there anyone that has a list of the codes that are able to give me a live data?

I can see that my obd2 adapter is fetching data as I can see the yellow lights blinking.
But no success with the code reading.

I tried several forums and a lot of manufacturers but noone has those codes. Everyone is giving me  a link to buy a new OBD2 adapter with their protocol. Maybe I need to change pin's?

But I am a programmer and I am making my own program for reading this live data.

Guys please help as this is urgent.

Comment: Does the scanner manufacturer state that this scanner is compatable with this vehicle?

Comment: I think as far as I could find it on the internet that yes, this is compatible with the scanner

Comment: Can you read any of the codes? I very seriously doubt you will have access to Mercedes Benz specific codes, without their software packages. Manufacturers are only required to give you access to OBD-II codes.

Comment: I need a OBD-II codes. As I only need to read live data such as speed, rpm and so on..  And I have my program written with the codes for OBD and I can't get any data from vehicle

Comment: I just put in a modest amount of research trying to figure this out with the info given, to no avail. This question is very old and still isn't really answerable without knowing the year of the vehicle and the details of "somehow I managed to get it in that OBD2 connector". Unfortunately, the OP hasn't been seen since Jan 2013.